# React how to change the div name on state change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, jsx

the section **"hdg-alert-popup"**, if the state is active it must be **"hdg-alert-popup active"**
while if the "hdg-button-login-container" *button is clicked* it must be "hdg-alert-popup", how can I do?

```html
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MessageError = (
  titolo: string,
  descrizione1: string,
  descrizione2: string,
  testoBottone: string,

) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);
  if (testoBottone == "") {
    testoBottone = "Chiudi questo avviso";
  }

  return (
    <section
      className="hdg-alert-popup"
    >

      <div className="hdg-login-popup">
        <div className="hdg-login-popup-container">
          <div className="hdg-login-popup-content">

            <h3 className="hdg-title">{parse(titolo)}</h3>
            <p>
              {descrizione1}
              {descrizione2 != "" && <b>{descrizione2}</b>}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="hdg-login-popup-error">
            <div className="hdg-button-login-container"><a href="#" className="hdg-button-back">{testoBottone}</a></div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default MessageError;
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking about basic react syntax

Comment: `className={"hdg-alert-popup" + (active ? " active":"")}`. stop being lazy, this is basic react syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be achieved with an active toggle?

```js
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MessageError = (
  titolo: string,
  descrizione1: string,
  descrizione2: string,
  testoBottone: string,

) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);
  if (testoBottone == "") {
    testoBottone = "Chiudi questo avviso";
  }

  return (
    <section
      className=`hdg-alert-popup ${active ? "active": '' }`
    >

      <div className="hdg-login-popup">
        <div className="hdg-login-popup-container">
          <div className="hdg-login-popup-content">

            <h3 className="hdg-title">{parse(titolo)}</h3>
            <p>
              {descrizione1}
              {descrizione2 != "" && <b>{descrizione2}</b>}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="hdg-login-popup-error">
            <div className="hdg-button-login-container" onClick={() => this.setActive(false)}><a href="#" className="hdg-button-back">{testoBottone}</a></div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default MessageError;
```

Comment: thank you very much, instead can you tell me why this condition does not work for me? {descrizione2 != "" && <b>{descrizione2}</b>}

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the `button` you can just set the *className* according with the state:

```
<div className={active ? "hdg-alert-popup": "hdg-button-login-container"} onClick={() => setActive(state => !state)}><a href="#" className="hdg-button-back">{testoBottone}</a></div>
```

For the `section`, you can do something similar:

```
<section className={`hdg-alert-popup ${active ? "active" : null}`}>
```

Comment: thank you very much, instead can you tell me why this condition does not work for me? {descrizione2 != "" && <b>{descrizione2}</b>}